# Laravel , relaciones entre dos modelos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7

Tengo dos modelos "Aliments" i "AlimentCategories" , la lógica es que un 1 alimento puede pernetecer a N "AlimentCategories"

Los modelos los tengo generados de esta manera

```
 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Aliments extends Model
 {
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'description', 'category_id'
];

public function category()
{
    $this->hasMany(AlimentCategories::class);
}
```

El otro modelo

```
 namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AlimentCategories extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'aliment_id','category_id','name','enabled'
];

public function aliments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Aliments::class);
}
```

No tengo claro si la relación deberia ser HasMany en ambos modelos , o una hasMany y belongsTo en el otro modelo.

El error que recibo al ejecutarlo desde tinker es el siguiente

> > > > $categories->aliments;
> > > >         Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'aliments.aliment_categories_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `aliments` where `aliments`.`alim
> > > >         ent_categories_id` = 1 and `aliments`.`aliment_categories_id` is not null)'

Comment: En tu modelo `AlimentCategories` la relación que el método debería reflejar deacuerdo a lo que mencionas es `belongsTo()` para asi ir de acuerdo a la relación de `1:N`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La representación en Laravel de la relación de `1:N` es con los métodos

- `hasMany()` 
  y
- `belongsTo()`

Si vamos al apartado de [relationships one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) podemos revisar que

> Una relación *uno a varios* es usada para definir relaciones donde un solo modelo posee cualquier cantidad de otros modelos, por ejemplo una publicación de un blog puede tener un número infinito de comentarios.

**EJEMPLO**

El siguiente código explica que dentro de la clase del modelo `Post` tenemos un método `comments()` para indicar que *un post puede tener muchos comentarios*

```
class Post extends Model
{
   public function comments()
   {
      return this->hasMany(Comment::class);
   }
}
```

Ahora en el siguiente fragmento de código, tenemos la representación inversa de la

```
class Comment extends Model
    {
       public function post()
       {
          return this->belongsTo(Post::class);
       }
    }
```

Dado lo anterior, tu modelo `Aliments` debería tener un método `categories` es plural para representar que un alimento puede tener muchas categorías

```
public function categories()
{
    $this->hasMany(AlimentCategories::class);
}
```

Y en tu modelo `AlimentCategories` debería quedar un método en singular de este modo, para identificar de un alimento su categoría

```
public function aliment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Aliments::class);
}
```